# iOS: "Flip-Clock" animation - how to?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

currently I´m working on an App where I like to implement a nice "flip-clock"-animation for numbers (like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKhsn-qrEZY).

It is realy hard to find a resource for an animation like this one I´m looking for. One of the best I found was this one: http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2010/04/10/creating-an-ipad-flip-clock-with-core-animation/

But I´m not very trusted with CoreAnimation. So it is hard to dive into the article I found. 
The article didnt describe all pieces in detail. As consequence (for me ;))the problem is that I have no idea where I have to start...

Did anyone know a good article / resource / place where I can find a better explained solution for such an animation? 
Or can someone help me to understand this article better?

Thank you!

Comment: The technique behind this effect is fairly straightforward. I wrote a demo application that's on Github: https://github.com/cbowns/flipclock after reading the voyce article you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a 3D transform on a UIView layer to rotate about any of the axis (or combination)...

```
CATransform3DMakeRotation(<#CGFloat angle#>, <#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat z#>)
```

This will rotate the view it is applied to by the angle (given in radians).. specify either 0 or 1 for the x, y and z values to decided whether or not to apply the angle rotation to that axis.

Now of course you can animate this transform by creating a normal `UIVIew beginAnimations` block, setting the transform and commiting the animation block.

To set the transform, use `[myView.layer setTransform:myTransform];`

Comment: Thank you. I just played a bit with CABasicAnimation / CATransform3DMakeRotation and it is now a bit more clear.
But now I have the problem that the animated view always jumps to the back of the view hierachy.
My animation is splited into two parts. In the animationDidStop delegate I start the second part of the animation but form this point of time the view stays in the back of the hierarchy.
I can't post Code (too few charachters left) sorry.
But did anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: WHen you rotate the views it can pass 'through' other layers due to the depth, you can set the layers zPosition to move it in front of (or behind) other layers.

Comment: Setting the zPosition didnt work for me. I tried this.
I recorded a short video of the problem: [Video](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1503795/FlipClock-ViewHierarchy.mpg)
So I didnt think this is a zPosition problem, what do you mean?

Comment: Ok, I set the zPosition for all layers bovor the animation starts.
This worked, thank you!